# Is it possible to get the focus distance of camera on ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, focus

I know by using getFocusDistances() can get the focus distance of camera on android.

As for ios, I searched a lot on internet but can't find any reference teaching me to do that. I don't know whether it is too simple for people to ask, or it is just impossible.

I just want to confirm if it is possible on IOS or not.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634518

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524998/distance-to-point-of-interest-in-iphone-auto-focus

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get Distance of Object from iPhone camera using image Exif meta data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634518/how-to-get-distance-of-object-from-iphone-camera-using-image-exif-meta-data)

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. It's not possible. Sorry.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It answers the question. The question is, "is it possible..?" And the answer is "no, it is not possible". I am not critiquing nor am I seeking clarification—there is nothing wrong with the question and it is perfectly clear—I am answering. It may not be a very long or technical answer, but it doesn't need to be.